# How to have different themes for each tag?

Tags: php, mysql

In my blog I need to have different themes ( CSS, menu, etc ) for each tag.

For example the tag "iPhone" has a page like "www.example.com/tag/iphone" and has

- a different CSS
- a different menu in the header
- other information related that tag.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Use a different class name (e.g. `iPhone_myclass`)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, 365 questions and 0 answers?` Maybe try giving back to the community?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the theme id in a cookie and when the guest visits your site you check the values of that cookie.

For example:

- When you have a new guest just show the default theme
- When the guest clicks on a link e.g `<a href="changeTheme.php?theme=black">BLACK THEME</a>` 
  you store that value from the theme variable in a cookie and when the user opens a page you should add the css for that theme e.g `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$_GET['theme'].'.css">'` .

But you need to have that .css files created.